# Which companions are longterm compatible for recruitment?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Having just finished my first play-through of BG3, I'm contemplating a replay. One of the things that would make a replay more interesting would be if I could recruit all the companions I failed to recruit last time. I managed to kill Karlach, Minthara, Jaheira and Minsc... so those 4 will be my top priority trying to recruit & keep in the party.

Reading up a bit regarding how to recruit the various characters, then:

> Recruiting Minthara seems to collide with Halsin's quest line and it definitely collides with Wyll and Karlach. Similarly, Wyll and Karlach quest lines might collide early on, Lae'zel and Shadowheart really don't like each other etc etc. Given that my first play-through was some 100+ hours I'd like to plan this ahead, spoilers be damned.

So I wonder which companions that are possible to keep in the same party while playing the game as intended: not skipping any quests but picking one route or the other ("good or evil choice" etc) and not exploiting any glitches. And also which companions that might ultimately end up trying to kill each other if not kept in check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The companions you can get are:

**Side with the Grove:**  Everyone except Minthara, though that can be changed [with mods](https://www.nexusmods.com/baldursgate3/mods/1713)

**Side with the Goblins:**  You can recruit Minthara, but lose Wyll, Karlach, and Halsin. Gale also leaves if you fail a skill check.

**Side with no one** *(enter the Shadow-Cursed Lands without picking a side)*:  Everyone except Halsin

There [used to be an exploit to get everyone](https://gameplay.tips/guides/baldurs-gate-3-recruiting-both-minthara-and-halsin.html) but it has since been patched.

---

There's a few other places where companions can permanently die/leave

**Act 1:**

> Lae'zel is killed by Shadowheart at night if you fail a skill-check

> Karlach can be optionally killed as part of Wyll's storyline

> Asterion can be optionally killed after he attempts to bite you

> Gale leaves if you don't feed him magic items

> Any companion can be sacrificed to Booooal

**Act 2:**

> Gale can blow himself up

> Shadowheart leaves if you free Nightsong without having her in the party

> Jaheira dies if you kill Nightsong

> Jaheira frequently dies on her own in the Moonrise Towers fight

**Act 3:**

> Gale can still blow himself up

> Astarion is sacrificed to Cazador if you don't free him or kill Cazador fast enough

> Jaheira leaves if you don't save Minsc

> Minsc dies if you don't have Jaheira in the party when you fight him

Comment: The "Minthara and Halsin" trick was actually patched out in the last patch. (They literally occupy the same space within the campsite, clipping on top of one another, otherwise).

Going this route still allows you "Everyone but Halsin".

Comment: @RavenDreamer Thanks for the info - updated!

Comment: Ok so it would seem that siding with nobody is the way to go then - I had Halsin in the party last playthrough. I read something about "you have to tell Minthara where the druids" are in order to recruit her later but I don't know if that is confirmed. Also potentially the goblin you can free from the druids could tell her, in case that affects anything.

Comment: @Amarth: I can accept the edit, but AFAIK it's not possible to free Astarion without killing Cazador?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yeah but it is an option (you assist him, like you would a knocked-down companion). From what I know you have two options, kill Cazador or let Astarion go through the ritual instead. In my playthrough I killed Cazador and freed Astarion early on. It's a pretty tough boss fight and doing it with just 3 characters might be a bit challenging, so I freed him asap. Then if he dies fighting it would be possible to revive him like usual.

Comment: @Amarth I can confirm that even if you don't interact with Minthara at all, you'll still be able to recruit her in Act 2.

Comment: @Amarth: I just tried this and wasn't able to free Astarion with an "assist" action. The only way was to kill Cazador.  So, I'm rejecting the edit.

Comment: Well what does the game call it then, "help"? I just walked up close to him and treated him as if he had been knocked out in combat. Pretty dang sure it is possible because in this fight Astarion and Cazador ended up in a neat 1 on 1 duel while the rest of my party killed off minions and disrupted the ritual. (Then eventually Shadowheart had to come in and steal the spotlight by dealing radiant damage and bonking Cazador in the head with Morninglord's Radiance... :))

Comment: Btw it should probably be possible for Will to get himself killed in the fight vs the goblins outside the Druid grove? It's a very easy fight but probably possible for him to die in theory?

Comment: @Amarth: I believe you can revive him. Same with Lae'zel getting killed by the other dragon riders. The one exception I've heard of is Jaheira in Moonrise Towers.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to revive anyone before they have joined your party. Tried that on Karlach, Jaheira, Minsc.

Comment: Another obvious thing we forget: in Act 1 Halsin can quite easily get killed 1) if you don't realize he's the bear and take the goblins side throwing rocks at him or just decide to leave him in the cage during the dialog, and 2) in case you free him he can die in the battle or in the upcoming battles. All before he joins your party.

Comment: @Amarth: Alright I just tried it again, and you're right, you can use 'help' to free Astarion. Normally you "left click" to help someone, but Astarion is, AFAIK, the only exception where you need to click the actual ability first.

Comment: You are allegedly able to get Minthara even when siding with the druids, now.